# Joomla 3 - how to add a subcategory button

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have joomla 3.0 withi this structure:

```
MAIN CAT 1 
- Subcategory  1
-- Documents
-- Video
-- Articles
- Subcategory  2
-- Documents
-- Video
-- Articles
MAIN CAT 2
...
```

I need to show all the subcat in a dropdown list under the "MAIN CAT 1". 
Then every subcat should show a page with 3 buttons respectively for: Documents / Video / Articles.

Those button should be created automatically for every Subcat ...

Have any ideas?

thanks a.

Answer (score 0):

Mabe **[this](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/drop-a-tab-menus/163)** will help... I myslef didn't use it, but the 4th point in the description states

*- navigate through sections, categories, content items (you can even make it expand regular section/category link menu items)*

so just give it a try..